# Looking for a more flexible tool than GNU indent

Tags: pretty-print, indentation

When I run indent with various options I want against my source, it does what I want but also messes with the placement of *s in pointer types:

```
  -int send_pkt(tpkt_t* pkt, void* opt_data);
  -void dump(tpkt_t* bp);
  +int send_pkt(tpkt_t * pkt, void *opt_data);
  +void dump(tpkt * bp);
```

I know my placement of *s next to the type not the variable is unconventional but how can I get indent to just leave them alone? Or is there another tool that will do what I want?  I've looked in the man page, the info page, and visited a half a dozen pages that Google suggested and I can't find an option to do this.

I tried Artistic Style (a.k.a. AStyle) but can't seem to figure out how to make it indent in multiples of 4 but make every 8 a tab.  That is:

```
if ( ... ) {
<4spaces>if ( ... ) {
<tab>...some code here...
<4spaces>}
}
```

Comment: Indenting by four spaces with eight-space tab stops is likely to aggravate everyone else who tries to maintain your code. Those who use four-space tabs (say, Visual Studio programmers) will believe you screwed up indentation. Those who use eight-space tabs won't like indenting four characters.

Comment: By the way, this is supposed to be [fixed in GNU indent 2.2.13](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/indent.git/commit/?id=22b83d68e9a8b429590f42920e9f473a236123cf), but I'm still seeing it, so apparently the fix is incomplete.

Answer (score 19):

**Uncrustify**

Uncrustify has several options on how to indent your files.

From the config file:

```
indent_with_tabs                           
  How to use tabs when indenting code  
  0=spaces only  
  1=indent with tabs, align with spaces  
  2=indent and align with tabs
```

You can find it [here](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/).

**BCPP**
From the website: *"bcpp indents C/C++ source programs, replacing tabs with spaces or the reverse. Unlike indent, it does (by design) not attempt to wrap long statements."*
Find it [here](http://invisible-island.net/bcpp/).

**UniversalIndentGUI**
It's a tool which supports several beautifiers / formatters. It could lead you to even more alternatives.
Find it [here](http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/).

**Artistic Style**
You could try [Artistic Style aka AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) instead (even though it doesn't do what you need it to do, I'll leave it here in case someone else finds it useful).

Comment: Plus 1, just tried out the universal indent gui with uncrustify, gives you "real-time" preview of a source file.

Comment: I am just playing with astyle and am already finding it nice

Answer (score 2):

Hack around and change its behavior editing the code. It's GNU after all. ;-)

As it's probably not the answer you wanted, here's another link: http://www.fnal.gov/docs/working-groups/c++wg/indenting.html.

Comment: That link doesn't work any more. It just redirects to the Fermilab homepage.