# C indentation tool

Tags: c, indentation

I have a bunch of C files and I need to check for a set of indentation rules. These rules are custom made. I basically need to flag warnings for all indentation violations. Is there any code/tool that does basic parsing of a C file. I am planning to add my own stuff to a code that already exists.

Comment: GNU indent is pretty customizable - have you looked into it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you plan on extending existing code, why not use [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)?

Once you have the correct flags it formats your code accordingly so that the results will always be the same. I (sadly) haven't found any dry-run flags, but a diff of your original file and the newly created astyle file should give you all violations.

Comment: I don't want the source files to be altered at all. Is there any tool that does this?

Comment: @nikhil If you don't want new files to be created, I am sadly out of options. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/101835/2328956 helps. I'd be interested if you find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can check out at [`clang-format`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html).  It has a `--dry-run` option that does not reformat the code.